# A joint short story

Tags: word-choice

Does "a joint short story", "a joint song",  etc sound natural?

I mean it is written by two or more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these are not idiomatic.  You can talk about the "joint authors" of a short story.  You might say "A collaborative short story", but this is also not completely clear.

The problem is that the authorship doesn't describe the story, so the adjective "joint" or "collaborative" needs to be applied to the writers, not to the story: "A story with joint authors" or a "jointly authored story".

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't really make sense - it would be more natural to just say a song written by 2 people, or a song jointly written by 2 people.